# How can I create a row of all dates in a month after specifying the month and year in a separate cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I want to do: specify the Month and Year in a cell and create a list of the dates in the specified month. So, it should look like this: the yellow cells are the only cells that should be changed by the user:

[image: Excel Example]

I only find examples where you have to manually pull the date down. But that's not what I want, the user should only need to specify month and year. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your version of Excel support SEQUENCE?

Comment: @BigBen yes, but the problem is that I have to specify the number of rows there, and not every month has the same number of days... Or is there another way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps could be shortened, but here is an approach using `DATEVALUE`, `DAY`, `SEQUENCE`, and `EOMONTH`. It may need adjusted based on the date format in your language/Excel settings.

```
=DATEVALUE(B1&SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(B1&" 1, "&B2),0)))&", "&B2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but sadly the formula does not work for me.

Comment: @Fabian - because most likely `DATEVALUE` (or its equivalent in your Excel install) is expecting a different format for the datestring. This example is using "May 1, 2021".

Comment: After copying the formula from your answer, I get the "There's a problem with this formula." error.

Comment: Does your version of Excel use `;` instead of `,`?

Comment: I will have a look, but here it looks like there is a problem with the formula itself...

Comment: Would I have to exchange every , with ;?

Comment: No, just the one in `..."&B2),0`. The others are part of the datestring, and fall inside quotes.

Comment: Well, ok that works. But now I get the #VALUE! error. Probably because of the wrong date format you mentioned. However, I can't really change that. Using the format cells thing does not work.

Comment: How would you write "May 1, 2021" in your version of Excel?

Comment: 1. May 21 is how I would do it in my version.

Comment: Try: `=DATEVALUE(SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("1. "&B1&" "&B2);0)))&". "&B1&" "&B2)`